# Pasar consulta SQL a Query Builder con función SUM

Tags: sql, laravel, querybuilder

Tengo esta consulta SQL y la quiero construir con Query Builder:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity*amount) AS total FROM concepts "
            . "INNER JOIN repairs ON repairs.id = concepts.repair_id "
            . "INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = repairs.customer_id "
            . "WHERE customers.id = $id";
```

He llegado hasta aquí:

```
$sql = DB::table('concepts')
            ->join('repairs', 'repairs.id', '=', 'concepts.repair_id')
            ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'repairs.customer_id')
            ->where('customers.id', $id)->sum('quantity', '*', 'amount');
```

En SQL sí obtengo el resultado correcto, con query builder sólo me hace el SUM de la primera columna (quantity) pero no lo multiplica por el segundo campo (amount)

Cómo hago el SUM(quantity*amount)?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera. Yo suelo poner un alias para estar seguro de como rescatar luego los datos

```
$sql = DB::table('concepts')
         ->join('repairs', 'repairs.id', '=', 'concepts.repair_id')
         ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'repairs.customer_id')
         ->where('customers.id', '=', $id)
         ->selectRaw('quantity * amount AS dinero')
         ->first();
```

Yo he usado first, porque entiendo es un solo resultado.
Puedes cambiar por `->get()` en caso que fueran mas de uno, y añadas el `group by` correspondiente.

Comment: En realidad la consulta lo que obtiene son todos los conceptos de todas las reparaciones de un cliente. Si pongo first() como me indicas entonces sólo obtengo la multiplicación de la cantidad por el precio del primer concepto de la primera reparación. Si pongo get() obtengo lo mismo pero de todos los conceptos... me falta hacer la suma total que es lo que busco, la suma de todos los conceptos... no logro hacer el sum()

Comment: Ahhh, ok! Si quieres el total, total, entiendo será así: `->selectRaw("SUM(quantity) * SUM(amount) AS dinero")`. Esto debería darte el total que ha gastado un cliente si te he entendido correctamente.

Comment: Ya lo tengo, para la suma de todos los conceptos de todas las reparaciones de un cliente sería así: ->selectRaw('SUM(quantity*amount) AS total')->get();